# Auto layout not set properly when give equal width constrains to buttons

Tags: ios, autolayout

I see many solution and applied auto layout constrains but still i am not getting desired solution.

Current Result:

[image: Result after Auto layout set]

Constrains given to all button:

[image: Constrains given to buttons]

View Hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: what is the desired solution that you want?

Comment: can you tell us if there are warnings on your storyboard controller ?

Comment: @Damien: it not given any warnings

Comment: @Rajan: Desire solution is equal width to all button like display in story board

Comment: @user2017279 Can you show the view heirarchy and also show the preview of all devices in this design.

Comment: @Rajan: I add the view heirarchy

Comment: @Rajan: First i take three button but it not work so i take three view and give constrains on view and take button inside view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what do you want is letting the 3 buttons equal each others and filling the width of screen using the Interface Builder (with no code, i.e: not programmatically), this is a solution:

*you don't need to add them in views.* just follow these steps:

let's start with this:

[image]

note that the buttons don't have any constraints -yet-, just add them to the to the bottom of the view (or where ever you want to display them, for this solution, I will display them in bottom of the screen). Make sure that the 3 of them have the same size.

**Adding constraints to the *orange* button:**

add the following constraints:
*leading, bottom space, and equal height.*

[image]

**Adding constraints to the *blue* button:**

add the following constraints:
*trailing, bottom space and equal height.*

[image]

**Adding constraints to the *cyan* button:**

- ctrl + drag from the cyan button to the orange button and add the following constraints: *horizontal spacing and center vertically.*

[image]

- ctrl + drag from the cyan button to the blue button and add the following constraints: *horizontal spacing.*

[image]

- *bottom space and equal height.*

[image]

So far so good, we are almost done!

Now, select the 3 buttons and add the following constraint: *equal widths.*

[image]

Your buttons should look like this:

[image]

Now, all you have to do is select each of the two *horizontal spacing* constraints and set their constants to 0 -from the size inspector-:

[image]

[image]

AND there you go:

[image]

I hope this helped, Cheers Up.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for solution in code.. .Swift 3.0:

```
    let button1 = UIButton()
    let button2 = UIButton()
    let button3 = UIButton()
    let buttons = [button1, button2, button3]
    button1.backgroundColor = .red
    button2.backgroundColor = .blue
    button3.backgroundColor = .green
    buttons.forEach {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview($0)
    }
    buttons.forEach {
        let cnt1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: $0, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let cnt2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: $0, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraints([cnt1, cnt2])
    }
    let cnt1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let cnt2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: button3, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let cnt3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button2, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: button1, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let cnt4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button3, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: button2, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let cnt5 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button2, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: button1, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let cnt6 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button3, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: button2, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraints([cnt1, cnt2, cnt3, cnt4, cnt5, cnt6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to lay out three buttons horizontally that have equal height and width? I think you can achieve this without using UIViews. I set constraints like as follows.

[image]

This is a simulator screenshot.

[image: Simulator screenshot]