# How to set autolayout constraints properly?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, autolayout

My GUI looks like that:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKqtd.png)

I don't really know how to set the constraints of the image view in the middle properly.
It works in portrait mode if I set constants but if I rotate the device it doesn't work anymore because the constant value is wrong for landscape.
Do you know how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

When you see a *red-lined* constraints that means the there is at least one missing constraint. When adding constraints to a component it should cover the whole frame of it (size: height/width and origin: x/y). If you want to let the height/width of the imageView dynamic (based on screen size), then you should add *Equal Widths* and *Equal Heights* constraints between the imageView and view container.

Also, in xcode 8, you can easily choose the desired size class, by choosing the device and its orientation. So, let's assume that you want to setup the constraints for all the iPads in landscape mode, in storyboard you should pick -for example-:

[image]

Also, you might want to check [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/) from WWDC 2016.

Hope this helped.

Comment: How can I set the landscape orientation in the storyboard so I can setup the constraints for portrait mode?

Comment: I assume that the answer shows it :) could you please elaborate?

Comment: I need to set the Y position for the image view in the middle and I don't know how to set that properly. If I add the missing constraint there is always a constant and I want to work without that constant

Comment: Well, if you want to let the three imageViews to be as the same height/width, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875373/auto-layout-not-set-properly-when-give-equal-width-constrains-to-buttons/39877740#39877740) might be useful for the logic of how you should achieve it, or simply, add them in a UIStackView.