# Can't get auto layout to make two buttons side by side stay there

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8

I'm at the point where I'm going crazy, I've tried everything to get these two buttons to stay where they are even if the device is changed. Any help at all would be amazing, this has been driving me crazy for hours.

[image]

Comment: what exactly is happening when they are "not standing where they are"? It is hard to help when we don't know what is wrong. You added (I assume) "before" state, what is "after" state?

Comment: @Lope I apologize for not stating what happens when I try to set my constraints. Either two things occur, one being that both the buttons shrink down and the other thing that happens is that one button overlaps when shown on a different device.

Comment: In addition to mentioning that using *stack view* should solve your problem, I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875373/auto-layout-not-set-properly-when-give-equal-width-constrains-to-buttons/39877740#39877740) to yours, all you have to do is to apply it on 2 buttons instead of 3.

Comment: @Yeah now we are getting somewhere :) gkaimakas' answer should work for you. If it still doesn't help you, post what constraints you have set up so we can take a look and see what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert those buttons into horizontal StackView component (which is available in iOS 9 and later) and set alignment to fill. Setup their constraints to have aspect ration on themselves and setup them to have equal width (at least that)... Much simpler approach IMO

see:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Comment: I'm so stupid totally forgot about StackView's.. Thank you so much, Dominik!

Comment: Hey, I just got home and followed what you said and It won't let me change the size of the buttons at all after I place them into a StackView. Picture: http://imgur.com/a/tk5Gs

Comment: @Yeah you just need to set the alignment to fill equally, sorry for not being specific

Answer (score 1):

Pin each button accordingly

- Left button at leading end
- Right button at trailing end
- Left & right button at bottom
- Left button horizontal spacing to right button
- Left button width equals right button width
- Left button height equals right button height
- Set the left button height to something e.g 64